# Executing batch file error: "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, working-directory

I am a newbie in java programming. I have this batch file called StartSample.bat. This batch file runs a java program. This is the code for the batch file:

```dos
@echo off
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;f3bc4jav.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;PalmSecureSample_Java.jar

@echo on
java <classname>
```

The .jar files mentioned above are on the same folder as the batch file.

When I run StartSample.bat, it executes the Java Program just as it should.

Now what I did was I created Java Class to run that batch file with this code:

```java
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /c start C:\\Identify\\dll\\StartSample.bat");
```

The error occurs when I run my code. The error is:

```
C:workspace\Project>java <classname> Error: Could not find or load main class <classname>
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: try adding `C:\\Identify\\dll\\f3bc4jav.jar` and `C:\\Identify\\dll\\PalmSecureSample_Java.jar`to the class path also check the canonical path to the Main class is given at `<classname>`

Comment: Are you trying to launch `<classname>` or it is only a placeholder?

Comment: @Noushad Hi, how can I check the absolute path of that main class?

Comment: `java com.xyz.path.to.MainClass.class`

Comment: @NicolasFilotto I'm not sure if I understood your question clearly.

Comment: @Noushad ah. Yes. That's was how it is coded. Except I didn't include the .class extension.

Comment: what does `<classname>` represent for you exactly?

Comment: @NicolasFilotta it is a class that calls the main frame class.

Comment: @Noushad update. I tried including the .class extension but it didn't work. I added the file path for the jar files but it resulted in to a different error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the batch file from your Java Class, the the batch files working directory is inherited by the working directory of your java environment.

To fix it, you should set the the path of your jar relative to the batch file with **%~dp0**:

```
@echo off
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%~dp0\f3bc4jav.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%~dp0\PalmSecureSample_Java.jar

@echo on
java <classname>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. I tried this. It throws an exception now. It is java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: Did the batch file now start your jar file ? Keep in mind that the called java program still inherits the working directory of the calling java program.

Comment: The batch file in itself executes just fine but when I try to execute the batch file through the java class, that's when it throws the exception.

Comment: So the former message does no longer occur:
    `C:workspace\Project>java <classname> Error: Could not find or load main class <classname>`. If that is the case, your first Problem is solved and the NullPointerException is a different case.

Comment: Yes. It doesn't return that error anymore. It now throws a NullPointerException.

Comment: C:workspace\Project>java <classname> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at <different classname> .

Comment: @Kylie If your question above is solved you may accept this answear. For the NullpointerException you may add another question including the code and the exception message

Answer (score 0):

Hello You may try with

```
@echo off
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;f3bc4jav.jar
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;PalmSecureSample_Java.jar

@echo on
java -cp %CLASSPATH% com.xyz.path.to.MainClass.class
```

Comment: Thanks for answering to my question. After trying this, I got this exception in my console: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException".

Comment: Hello Kylie, Its because of problem with your code. If not sensitive, please edit the question and share your main class source code.